# использовать результат запроса в нескольких других запросах

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть таблица users, в ней поля id, status, group.

Нужно вывести количество юзеров с группой 1 и статусами 1,2,3 (на каждый статус свое значение)

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE group='1' AND status='1';") or die(printBdError());
$x=mysql_num_rows($select);  
$select = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE group='1' AND status='2';") or die(printBdError());
$y=mysql_num_rows($select); 
$select = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE group='1' AND status='3';") or die(printBdError());
$z=mysql_num_rows($select);
```

Как это сделать за один запрос и не производя повторной выборки?

Comment: В запросе не указываете статус, а потом с помощью цикла пройдитесь по полученному списку.

Comment: Группировка! `SELECT status, count(*) FROM users WHERE group='1' group by status`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id,SUM(status=1),SUM(status=2),SUM(status=3)
FROM users 
WHERE `group`=1
GROUP BY id
```